# Reshape data for values in one column

Tags: r, dataframe, reshape, melt

My data.frame looks like this

```
ID | test | test_result
1  |  B   |   10
2  |  A   |   9
3  |  A   |   11
4  |  C   |   7
5  |  F   |   5
```

And I want to get something like this:

```
test | test_reult_ID1 | test_result_ID2 | test_result_ID3 ...
 A   |   NA           |     9           |   11
 B   |   10           |     NA          |   NA
```

It works with reshape() to the wide format with only a few cases but with the whole data frame (about 23.000 ID´s) reshape () takes too long.
Melt() and cast() do reshape the data but replace the values in test_result by the frequency of the test. Any other ideas how to manage this? Thanks!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9617424/210673 now has a list of the various ways to do this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

dcast from the reshape2 package does this:

```
require(reshape2)
dcast(data, test ~ ID , value_var = 'test_result' )

#  test  1  2  3  4  5
#1    A NA  9 11 NA NA
#2    B 10 NA NA NA NA
#3    C NA NA NA  7 NA
#4    F NA NA NA NA  5
```

Comment: I´ve just tried it with he whole data.frame and it gives me this error message: `Aggregation function missing: defaulting to length` and again only the frequencies instead of the values. With only a few rows however in works. Do you know why?

Comment: @Elisa This will happen when your `dcast` arguments result in more than one value in each cell of the result.  If this happens, some kind of aggregation needs to happen, and the default function is count. Do you perhaps have duplicate values in your data?  Anyway, perhaps try `mean` as the aggregation function.

Comment: @Andrie: the aggregation function stops the errors but apparently `mean` doesn´t work because: `argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA` Is there any aggregation function like "just return the values" ?

Comment: Your problem is that there is more than one value to return, so you need to find a function that collapses multiple values into a single value.  If your data is of class `character`, perhaps consider using `paste`?

Comment: solved it: the problem was that one ID for some reason had three instead of two rows. the duplicated() solved that then.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution using `reshape` function in `base` R.

```
reshape(mydf, direction = 'wide', idvar = 'test', timevar = 'ID', 
  v.names = 'test_result', sep = "_")
```

EDIT. I see that you have already tried `reshape` and it took too long. Can you provide more details on your actual data?

Comment: My original data has those three columns and about 23000 rows. There is the same ID for two rows each (one person has solved two tests, e.g A and F and therefore two results and two rows). Might that be the problem?