# Reshaping data with count

Tags: r, reshape2

I have a dataset and I want to reshape it with package reshape2 from R, but I'm getting this error:

```
Aggregation function missing: defaulting to length
```

This is the head() of my data:

```
cat_one customer valor
cama        A     1
cama        B     1
cama        C     1
mesa        D     1
mesa        A     1
mesa        A     1
```

And I want to reshape it like this, with a count between both variables:

```
customer     cama    mesa
A             1       0
B             2      ...
C
D            ...     ...
```

This is my code:

```
dcast(dados_teste, cat_one ~ customer, value.var = 'valor')
```

And I'm following this other [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8093839/reshape-data-for-values-in-one-column), but the same solution is not working for me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You've mixed up the LHS and RHS of the formula.

Try:

```
library(reshape2)
dcast(dados_teste, customer ~ cat_one, value.var = "valor")
# Aggregation function missing: defaulting to length
#   customer cama mesa
# 1        A    1    2
# 2        B    1    0
# 3        C    1    0
# 4        D    0    1
```

The "error" that you refer to is actually just a `warning` that tells you that it is just counting the number of values--not applying any other function. So, in this case, it's perfectly acceptable.

If you want to get rid of it, specify `fun.aggregate = length`.

```
dcast(dados_teste, customer ~ cat_one, 
      value.var = "valor", fun.aggregate = length)
```

---

If its just counts of two columns that you're after, you could also look at `table`:

```
as.data.frame.matrix(table(dados_teste[c(2, 1)]))
#   cama mesa
# A    1    2
# B    1    0
# C    1    0
# D    0    1
```